# How do I pass same number rows to Google Charts API with data from Analytics API

Tags: php, arrays, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get some data from Analytics API and then display it Area Charts using Google Charts API.

The following array contains data for two days from Analytics API v4. The screenshot shows how the data is returned/rendered in a Table in Query Explorer.

[image: screenshot]

```
<?php
    $results = [
      0 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Organic Search',
          1 => '20160831',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '13',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      1 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Social',
          1 => '20160830',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '7',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      2 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Organic Search',
          1 => '20160830',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '6',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      3 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Social',
          1 => '20160831',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '6',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      4 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Referral',
          1 => '20160831',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '3',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      5 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Referral',
          1 => '20160830',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '2',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      6 => 
      [
        'dimensions' => 
        [
          0 => 'Direct',
          1 => '20160830',
        ],
        'metrics' => 
        [
          0 => 
          [
            'values' => 
            [
              0 => '1',
              1 => '0',
              2 => '0.0',
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ];

?>
```

I am trying to plot the Default Channel Grouping and Sessions data for a period of 30 days into an Area Chart. The data format accepted by the chart is as follows:

```
[
  [
    {
      "label": "Day",
      "id": "day"
    },
    {
      "label": "Organic Search",
      "id": "organic_search",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "label": "Referral",
      "id": "referral",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "label": "Social",
      "id": "social",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "label": "Direct",
      "id": "direct",
      "type": "number"
    }
  ],
  [
    "20160831",
    "13",
    "3",
    "0",
    "6"
  ],
  [
    "20160830",
    "1",
    "6",
    "2",
    "7"
  ]
]
```

Here's my code to try to get the API data into the Array for the Charts.

```
<?php

function getChartData($rows)
{
    // Get the unique dates
    $dates = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $dates[] = $row['dimensions'][1];
    }
    $dates = array_unique($dates);

    // get the uniqe dimensions
    $dimensions = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $dimensions[] = $row['dimensions'][0];
    }
    $dimensions = array_unique($dimensions);

    // Put all the values and the dimension filtered by date
    $values = [];
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if ($date == $row['dimensions'][1]) {
                $val = $row['metrics'][0]['values'];
                array_push($val, $row['dimensions'][0]);
                array_unshift($val, $date);
                $values[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    // Group the sessions metric value by date
    $chartValues = [];
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        $val = [];
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if ($date == $value[0]) {
                $val[] = $value[1];
            }
        }
        array_unshift($val, $date);
        $chartValues[] = $val;
    }

    return $chartValues;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the API doesn't always return the exact same number of channel groupings for each day.

For instance, for August 31st there is no direct Traffic session data. When this is passed as is to charts, it fails because it always expects the values to always to have the same number of items in the array.

How could I add an empty value when any of the Channel Grouping Session data is missing so that Area Charts array will always receive the same number of values for each day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to get it working if anyone has the same issue:

```
<?php

function getAreaChartValues($response) 
{
    // Get the rows of the response
    $rows = $response->toSimpleObject()->reports[0]['data']['rows'];

    $dimensions = [];

    $results = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        // Add all the dimensions to the dimensions array
        $dimensions[] = $row['dimensions'][0];

        $date = isset($row['dimensions'][1]) ? $row['dimensions'][1] : '';
        $ValueType = $row['dimensions'][0];
        $value = $row['metrics'][0]['values'][0];

        if (!isset($results[$date])) {
            $results[$date] = [];
        }

        $results[$date][$ValueType] = $value;
    }

    ksort($results);

    $dimensions = array_unique($dimensions);

    // Check for any non existant value for a dimension 
    // And add empty values
    foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
        foreach ($results as &$result) {
            if (!array_key_exists($dimension, $result)) {
                $result[$dimension] = 0;
            }
            ksort($result);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a `null` value

```
        if ($date == $row['dimensions'][1]) {
            $val = $row['metrics'][0]['values'];
            array_push($val, $row['dimensions'][0]);
            array_unshift($val, $date);
            $values[] = $val;
        } else {
            $val = null;
            array_push($val, $row['dimensions'][0]);
            array_unshift($val, $date);
            $values[] = $val;
        }
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't like the null value either. So came up with a different solution which I have posted for reference.